# React native v6: tab bar customization

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i have a bottom tab in my react native application, when i try to edit the tabBarStyle on the tab navigator it doesnt work. It only works on 1 out of my 3 tabs for some reason.

Only the help tab follows the required design the home and the test tab remain as default. I have tried all solutions only add made sure that i am using screenOptions and tabBarStyle instead of style.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor:'white',
  tabBarLabelStyle:{
    fontWeight:'700'
  },
  tabBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor:'black',
    borderTopColor: 'black',
    elevation: 0,   // for Android
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0, height: 0 // for iOS
  },
    height:Platform.OS==='ios'&& dimen.width>400?80:Platform.OS==='ios'&& dimen.width<400?60:50,
}  
}}
    initialRouteName={"Home"}
    >
      
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color,focused }) => (
          <Entypo name="home" size={30} color={'#969696'}/>
            ),
            headerShown:false,
            unmountOnBlur: true,
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Test"
        component={TestNavigator}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabBarButton: () => (
            <NewListingButton
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.test)}
            />
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
            <FontAwesome
              name="life-saver"
              size={size}
              color={color}
            />
          ),
          headerShown: false,
          unmountOnBlur: true,
        })
      }
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Help"
        component={HelpNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color,focused }) => (
            <Ionicons name="help" size={30} color={'#969696'}/>
            ),
            unmountOnBlur: true,
            headerShown:false,
        }}
      />

    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with react navigation 6 in order to hide the tab navigator on specific screens i had to set the tabBarStyle display to none, which was why the background wasnt changing if the tab had a stack